# Oracle apex pie chart percentage and display

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I am trying to display a pie chart on Oracle Apex as a percentage of each response of why a deal was rejected etc. The value of each chunk shows as equal chunks until you hover over the piece which shows it's value coming back in thousands rather than a percentage of 100. I know on the attributes setting of the pie chart you can put it as a percentage and on the format scaling the options are: Thousand, Million, Billion, Trillion and quadrillion. The SQL code I have for the pie chart is as follows

```
SELECT * FROM DEALS_RETURNED;
```

Deals_returned is the table name but I want it to count the column 'Reason' to show on the pie how many of each reason has been given for each rejected etc.

Tried to change the code to have

```
SELECT COUNT(Reason)
FROM DEALS_RETURNED
```

Comment: See examples for Pie charts as you need them here: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/r/apex_pm/sample-charts/pie

Comment: @MónicaGodoy This doesn't help my question. I'm looking for an SQL query which will resolve this as I am unable to use what you have provided

Comment: @user19600836, see the Donut Chart (Sorting).
Label Display As - The new series-level attribute is set to Percentage ( Value ), rendering the label in that format, without the need to use custom JavaScript code to acomplish it.